# NicePlayer lost its playback

Tags: macos

I somehow broke NicePlayer. Once I open a video with it. The timer starts - but video doesn't appear.

Have tried both CoreVideo and QuickTime as the video Plugins.

Anyone have any ideas as to why this is happening?

Thank you.

EDIT:

Perian is installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been having a lot of issues with Perian lately. I'm not using NicePlayer but QuickTime, and I face the same issue as you where it sometimes complains that the codec is not available (using different words).

My current solution is to disable and re-enable Perian. Go to the Perian System Preference pane, click *Remove Perian* and then click *Install Perian*, the same button. After this, the same videos tend to work again.

Comment: HAHAHA - I can't believe it - but doing EXACTLY that - worked :)

Thank you.